# Get latest records of each number in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have set of data in `Trans` table. Which contains several transactions of `transno`. I need to get latest transaction record of each `transno`.
These data stored in Oracle database.

[image]

I have tried below query, with few changes in every time. But i gives only one raw. This table contain more than 1m records.

`select * from (select  transid,transno,transdate,transtype
from trans order by TRANSID desc) where rownum <= 1`

Please help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the latest `transdate` for all the `transno`

```
select * from 
(
select  transid,transno,transdate,transtype,
Row_number()over(partition by transno order by transdate desc) as rn
from trans
) where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank You verymuch. I got the exact output from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works.

```
SELECT * FROM trans GROUP BY transno ORDER BY transid DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm not a MySQL master, so let me know.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the effort. But didn't get desired output. and few errors returned. Prdp's answer is giving the correct output. It tooks more time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this solution is @Prdp's way. But there is another way too. You can use `inline view` like this:

```
select * from 
trans t
inner join 
(
   select transno, max(transdatetime) maxtransdatetime from trans group by transno
) s
on s.transno = t.transno and s.maxtransdatetime = t.transdatetime
```

Comment: There's no JOIN going on here.

Comment: @PHPglue, I know and I have noted that this way is not the best, but this is another solution of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.